# How can I use Axios to access the JSON data within a response sent using Expressjs?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, http, axios

I'm creating a web application that generates a pdf on a server then sends it to the client for display within the browser.

The client is using Vuejs / Axios to send a POST request. Afterwards, The server is receiving it with Expressjs, generating a unique PDF, converting the file to a base64 value then sending it back as a response.

I cannot seem to get the response correct. When I attempt to display `response.data.pdfData` within the client I get undefined in the console. I can see that there is indeed a response with the key and value pair using inspection tools within the Network tab under the Preview section but cannot seem to access it.

```
// FILE: ./Client/src/App.vue
    submit(personalInfo) {
      this.cardInfo.personalInfo = personalInfo;
      console.log('Sending POST preview_card...');
      axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/preview_card',
        method: 'POST',
        responseType: 'blob',
        data: {
          cardInfo: this.cardInfo,
        },
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.pdfData);
      });
    },
```

```
 // FILE: ./Server/app.js
app.post('/api/preview_card', (req, res) => {

  // Generate pdf
  const doc = new jsPDF('p');
  doc.setFontSize(40);
  doc.text(req.body.cardInfo.templateInfo, 100, 100);
  doc.save('response.pdf');

  // Convert pdf to base64
  var tempFile = path.resolve(__dirname, './response.pdf');
  var pdfBase64 = fs.readFileSync(tempFile).toString('base64');

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return res.send(JSON.stringify({ pdfData: pdfBase64 }));
});
```

[image: Inspection Tools]

I find it necessary to serve the pdf this way due to my client's compnents as well as to enforce a level of data coherency between concurrent users.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `responseType: 'json'` in your `axios` call?

Comment: This was it! A sign I should go to sleep. Thank you